# How to use browser validation on submit without blocking the submit handler

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, form-submit, client-side-validation

HTML5 lets us submitting forms from a button outside the form.

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input required/>
</form>
<button type="submit" form="myform"/>
```

This doesn't work well with React apparently as you can see in the following snippet.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState("");

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!value) {
      setResult("Error");
    } else {
      setResult(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <form id="myform" className="box" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <h3>My form</h3>
        <input
          className="input"
          value={value}
          required
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
      <button type="submit" form="myform" className="button">
        Submit
      </button>
      <div>Result: {result}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgb(10 10 10 / 10%), 0 0 0 1px rgb(10 10 10 / 10%);
  color: #4a4a4a;
  display: block;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 2.25em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #363636;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I would expect the "Result" box to show "Error". Instead, the browser validation kicks in and the form submit handler is not called at all.

Am I doing something wrong?

### Edit

Thanks to the comments to this post I realized that I based my question on a wrong assumption: that having the submit button outside a (invalid) form was causing the browser to prevent the execution of the submit handler. Instead, this is just the normal behavior of any form with validation and a submit handler.

So, if we wanted to salvage this question, this is what I would like to achieve on form submit:

- All fields are automatically validated by the browser.
- Default balloon messages are not shown.
- The submit handler is called anyway so that I can graciously show the error messages.

I worked around it by using a simple click handler on the button instead of the submit handler on the form. But it would be nice to still use the submit button and handler and just disable the browser behaviours to prevent the submit handler execution and show the balloon messages.

Comment: The only thing "wrong" is that you expect the submit function to call before the browser validation.

Comment: Do you want to keep the validation and get the desired output at the same time? You have `required ` attribute in your input field, which is a client side HTML5 validation

Comment: You can add `noValidate` to the `form` if you want to skip the browser validation.

Comment: @Tushar Yes, I'd like to keep the browser validation and get the desired output at the same time. I guess it's not possible? 

EDIT: More specifically, I'd like the browser to do its validations (e.g. mark fields as not valid) but I don't want it to show those ugly blocking messages.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_forms_using_javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about the existence of the [invalid event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/invalid_event). It is raised when a form submission is attempted with invalid data. This event's default can be prevented to avoid the browser showing the default warning balloons. The logic for showing the validation errors can be implemented in the invalid event handler and let the submit handler only worry about submitting the validated data.

```
<form onInvalid={e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // show validation errors
} onSubmit={e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // Submit data
}>
  <input required/>
  <button type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have marked the field as required. You need to remove that.

```
<input className="input" value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState("");

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!value) {
      setResult("Error");
    } else {
      setResult(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <form id="myform" className="box" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <h3>My form</h3>
        <input
          className="input"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
      <button type="submit" form="myform" className="button">
        Submit
      </button>
      <div>Result: {result}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgb(10 10 10 / 10%), 0 0 0 1px rgb(10 10 10 / 10%);
  color: #4a4a4a;
  display: block;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 2.25em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #363636;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```